# Can't make this simple ASP.NET tutorial code run

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, postman

I followed the instructions of this [excellent ASP.NET tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=J_MEscBWJYI), but I can't get it to work at all after trying for hours.

There is nothing wrong with the code, but, either the server is not responding according to Postman or there is a runtime exception that is not triggered. I must admit that I'm completely new to ASP.NET so I don't really know what else to do.

I made a public repo on [Github](https://github.com/eduFDiaz/ToDoListWebApi) for convenience. Thanks in advance for the help.

[image: The project structure]

StartUp.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using ToDoListWebApi.Services;

namespace ToDoListWebApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddSingleton<IIventoryServices, InventoryServices>();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

InventoryController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ToDoListWebApi.Models;
using ToDoListWebApi.Services;

namespace ToDoListWebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("v1/")]
    [ApiController]
    public class InventoryController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly InventoryServices _services;

        public InventoryController(InventoryServices services)
        {
            _services = services;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("AddInventoryItems")]
        public ActionResult<InventoryItems> AddInventoryItems(InventoryItems items)
        {
            var inventoryItems = _services.AddInventoryItems(items);

            if (inventoryItems == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return inventoryItems;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetInventoryItems")]
        public ActionResult<Dictionary<string,InventoryItems>> GetInventoryItems()
        {
            var inventoryItems = _services.GetInventoryItems();

            if (inventoryItems.Count == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return inventoryItems;
        }
    }
}
```

InventoryItems.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ToDoListWebApi.Models
{
    public class InventoryItems
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

IInventoryServices.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ToDoListWebApi.Models;

namespace ToDoListWebApi.Services
{
    public interface IIventoryServices
    {
        InventoryItems AddInventoryItems(InventoryItems items);
        Dictionary<string, InventoryItems> GetInventoryItems();
    }
}
```

InventoryServices.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ToDoListWebApi.Models;

namespace ToDoListWebApi.Services
{
    public class InventoryServices : IIventoryServices
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, InventoryItems> _inventoryItems;

        public InventoryServices()
        {
            _inventoryItems = new Dictionary<string, InventoryItems>();
        }

        public InventoryItems AddInventoryItems(InventoryItems items)
        {
            _inventoryItems.Add(items.ItemName, items);

            return items;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, InventoryItems> GetInventoryItems()
        {
            return _inventoryItems;
        }
    }
}
```

Json query parameters for the url https://localhost:port/v1/AddInventoryItems

```
{
  "Id": "1",
  "ItemName": "Weed Eater",
  "Price": 430
}
```

Postman screenshoot:
[image: Postman screenshoot]

Comment: @bolkay Is it because my post doesn't include any code?

Comment: Yes. You (I think ) stand a better chance of getting your problem solved if you have a 'specific" aspect of your codebase that you think is the cause of the issue.

Comment: @bolkay Thanks for the advice, I added some code now, hope it can make everything clear for everyone. I don't know where to start looking for an answer.

Comment: You seem to have followed his tutorial to the dot,but he removed this code,app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });

Comment: @Peter  Just tried that, didn't work. Thanks for noticing that small difference in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up following this tutorial, there are a lot of mistakes that don't trigger an exception but if you compare with this tutorial [from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1) you can realize this was not the best first approach to how to build a web Api using ASP.NET. Thanks anyway to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make this a comment if I had enough rep. Have you made sure IIS is running? Should see it in the hidden icons toolbar on your desktop

Comment: Yes, IIS was running, I can see the Hello World! start page. But when trying to post a new item, it doesn't trigger an exception or returns an answer from it.